# Mocking complex return types

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I am a newbie with `powermock, mockito` and facing an issue with complex return types.
Example: Suppose the following method needs to be mocked:

```
public someReturnType getMethod(param1, param2){
   ....
   ....
   return someMethod(param1);
}
```

I am facing an issue while mocking `someMethod(param1)`. Since, there is business logic getting executed before this call, it makes no sense in just replacing a mock of this return call. Please advice.

Comment: The intention of mockito or similar frameworks is to omit executing business logic; so if possible you should just return some default value.

Comment: It is unclear to me whether you ask about mocking `getMethod` (following the sentence just before the code extract) or `someMethod` (following the sentence just after the code extract). You may want to clarify that.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I want to mock getMethod(param1, param2). But this method returns someReturnType which is calculated by another method someMethod(param1). The dilemma is if i don't mock the someMethod(param1) method then it returns null but if i mock it then i am skipping the earlier business logic.

Comment: If you mock someMethod and call getMethod with the contained business logic in your test, then you would test exactly the business logic in getMethod; isn't that what you want?

Comment: It is important to understand that if you mock `getMethod(param1, param2)`, the content of the actual implementation you use in the production code will never be used. Instead, you have to configure the mock object to return an instance of `someReturnType` corresponding to the provided parameters. In that context, `someMethod(param1)` is irrelevant since it is not executed. Judging by the title of your question though, it seems the problem you try to tackle is the complexity of the `someReturnType` objects; but you do not say much in the question description...

Comment: public MyOwnRoom getMyRoom(String id) {
        MyRoom mr = someRepository.load(MyRoom.class, id);

        if (mr == null)
            return null;

        MyRooms rooms = new MyRooms(mr);

        rooms.setRoom(roomRepository.getRoom(mr));

        if (rooms.getRoom() != null)
            rooms.setBed(bedRepository(rooms.getRoom()));
        
        ...
  ...

        if (rooms.getCamera() != null)
            setVideo(rooms.getCamera());

        return myAssembler.get(rooms);
    } I am not sure how to mock myAssembler.get(rooms) coz if we don't mock it getMyRoom(String id) returns null.

Comment: Could you edit your question instead? Also, be clear about what you want to test and what you think you should mock for that, as well as what is blocking you there.

Comment: The question i am trying to ask is, how do you mock if there are hundred business functions(private functions) applied on that object from its creation to the point where we want to apply the mock.           Ex. A a = new A();   ....... /*n number of private methods called on a.*/             a = repository.getMethod();//function which we want to mock.

Answer (score 0):

So let's say for argument sake, that `somemethod(param1, param2)` is a service class that your testing and the `somemethod(param1)` is calling your DAO accessing your database. Since your in your test case why spin up all that overhead for a test database and such, when you can just mock it. This makes your test cases faster and easier to write because your testing the class itself and not the classes below that it access. But you would want to verify that it indeed got called by `Mockito.verify(mockSomeMethod, Mockito.times(1)).someMethod(Mockito.eq(param1));`

or that it never got called by `Mockito.never()` in place of `Mockito.times(count)` The idea is to test the business logic in the class your testing, and not having to setup everything below the business logic just to get a valid return value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, let me reframe my question though,
I have some legacy code which has constructors and business logic like,
public MyReturnType getMyMethod(String id){
 /*Other code*/
 MyClass clazz = new MyClass();
 clazz.setHeight();
 clazz.setWidth(repository.getWidth());
 /*Other getters and setters*/
 MyReturnType returnValue = assembler.assemble(clazz);
 return returnValue;
}
I would like to know how to mock the call assembler.assemble(clazz), since
there are many getters and setters prior to that call.

Comment: More often than not legacy code has grown in a way that makes unit testing (and mocking, with it) nearly impossible, as there are no real testable units; everything is interweaved with everything. It is in dire need for refactoring - but refactoring without unit tests is risky. That is a known dilemma, and there are some books about this issue. But I fear it is impossible to give a concise solution for this problem in this context.